# Download all related .PDF file for specif topic with depth

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am very new to python and scrapy.,my task is to download .PDF files for a specif topic. Ex : There was a more contracts in this site ** https://www.sec.gov/ ** currently i am downloading the files one by one. I have to write a scrapy program to download all related .PDF files using search key word like ** Keyword : Exhibit 10/ EXHIBIT 11 **

```
## My Code ##

    #import urllib
import scrapy

from scrapy.http import Request

class pwc_tax(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "pwc_tax"

  allowed_domains = ["www.sec.gov"]
  start_urls = ["https://www.sec.gov/cubist-pharmaceuticals-inc-exhibit-10-65-10-k405"]

  def parse(self, response):
    base_url = 'https://www.sec.gov/'

    for a in response.xpath('//a[@href]/@href'):
        link = a.extract()
        # self.logger.info(link)

        if link.endswith('.pdf'):
            #link = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, link)
        link = base_url + link
            self.logger.info(link)
            yield Request(link, callback=self.save_pdf)

  def save_pdf(self, response):
    path = response.url.split('/')[-1]
    self.logger.info('Saving PDF %s', path)
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

Using This scrapy code I can able to download PDF only in given URL.
EX : https://www.sec.gov/cubist-pharmaceuticals-inc-exhibit-10-65-10-k405
(If I gave above URL the file has been downloading but for this I can download by manually, I have to download the whole PDF which was search item ) 
if I search using **Exhibit 10** keyword the follwing page will appear https://secsearch.sec.gov/search?utf8=%3F&affiliate=secsearch&query=exhibit+10  and I want to scrapy to open all links and download all the pdf. If any one help me with solve this code. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first take the search query url in `start_urls` and from the response of start_url, extract all the urls and send request to each one of them. After that extract the pdf link and save it to your local storage.

The code will look something like this,

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.http import Request


class pwc_tax(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pwc_tax"

    allowed_domains = ["www.sec.gov", 'search.usa.gov', 'secsearch.sec.gov']
    start_urls = ["https://secsearch.sec.gov/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&affiliate=secsearch&sort_by=&query=Exhibit+10%2F+EXHIBIT+11"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # extract search results
        for link in response.xpath('//div[@id="results"]//h4[@class="title"]/a/@href').extract():
            req = Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_page)
            yield req

    def parse_page(self, response):
        # parse each search result here
        pdf_files = response.xpath('//div[@class="article-file-download"]/a/@href').extract()
        # base url wont be part of this pdf_files
        # sample: [u'/files/18-03273-E.pdf']
        # need to add at the beginning of each url
        # response.urljoin() will do the task for you
        for pdf in pdf_files:
            if pdf.endswith('.pdf'):
                pdf_url = response.urljoin(pdf)
                req = Request(url=pdf_url, callback=self.save_pdf)
                yield req

    def save_pdf(self, response):
        path = response.url.split('/')[-1]
        self.logger.info('Saving PDF %s', path)
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Jithin, I have replaced with your code and the code has been executed but I can't see any file was downloaded in this directory. What should i want to do now ?

Comment: set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` in your `settings.py` file. Make sure that you have updated the allowed_domains to `allowed_domains = ["www.sec.gov", 'search.usa.gov', 'secsearch.sec.gov']`

Comment: Hello Jithin, Am sorry, I don't know where to get the Error details. Are you asking my terminal screenshot ????

Comment: did you make the changes i mentioned above? Because its working for me.

Comment: Thank you very much Jithin, I have added the All domains and pdf has been downloading successfully. You saved my Job. Thanks once again.

Comment: Last Doubt, If I have to search some other document what are the changes I have to change ?? Only I want to change the URL ? Is that enough ? or want to change any other details. I mean for EX : If I want to get document in **Exhibit 10 ** I want to change this URL ** https://secsearch.sec.gov/search?utf8=%3F&affiliate=secsearch&query=exhibit+10 ** and I want to search this keyword ** Exhibit 11 ** and I want to use this URL ** https://secsearch.sec.gov/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&affiliate=secsearch&sort_by=&query=exhibit+11 **

Comment: change the start-url or add one more function to dynamically add those things

Comment: Thanks and If I give Exhibit 10 it want to search and download the document like Exhibit 10, Exhibit 10.1, 10.2, 10.3 etc.., It has been check and download what are the document has been linked to Exhibit 10., So what are the changes I have to do.

Comment: In this link it has 5 pages, How to I set depth to search all the pages and download all the PDF which is related to Exhibit 10

Comment: I have tried this link from advanced search to get document, but it haven't downloaded. Code has been executed but nothing happens. this is the link.
https://searchwww.sec.gov/EDGARFSClient/jsp/EDGAR_MainAccess.jsp?search_text=exhibit%2010&sort=Date&formType=Form8K&isAdv=true&stemming=true&numResults=10&querySic=3571&fromDate=10/31/2014&toDate=10/31/2017&numResults=10  . I have added the domain also, **searchwww.sec.gov**.

Comment: I have tried to download documents in this URL [link] ( https://searchwww.sec.gov/EDGARFSClient/jsp/EDGAR_MainAccess.jsp?search_text=exhibit%2010&sort=Date&formType=Form10K&isAdv=true&stemming=true&numResults=10&querySic=3571&fromDate=10/31/2014&toDate=10/31/2017&numResults=10 ) but It haven't downloaded. I noticed that the document was in **htm** format. So how to download PDF and htm  formats too...